# How to switch between original DOM and the DOM changed by a Content script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome Extension that changes the DOM of a page. But I would like to give the user an option to switch between the page before the changes and the changed page.

It's a little bit like Google translate where you can change between the orginal language and the translated message.

I could not find anything in my own searches.

I know JavaScript but not JQuery yet.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the entire body in a variable, then start overwriting things. If you want to switch back load up the old body.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But as i am a noob to javascript, how do i put a hole DOM in one variable and how do i change a copy of that variable. Because document.getElementbyId probably won't work.

Comment: Wouldn't that save just a reference to the body element? And if you do try to make a copy of DOM, you typically lose event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You could save all the original DOM content to a variable before running the content script. You can do this by using the following code at the top of your content script:

```
var originalDOM = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

This saves the entire DOM in an array called `originalDOM`. The `*` acts a universal tag, requesting every tag in the document. You can read more about the `.getElementsByTagName()` API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: But those probably are not copies but references to elements. If you modify something in the DOM after this, then `originalDOM` will contain the same changes. Besides, that _particular_ function returns a list of all elements and not simply a tree of all elements. I fail to see this as useful.

Comment: @Xan That is a good point. See my other answer (I am keeping this answer up just for reference).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
var page = html.innerHTML;
```

This will give you everything between the `<html>` tags.
After the content script is injected, run:

```
var newPage = html.innerHTML;
```

Now, whenever you want to switch between the pages, simply run:

```
html.innerHTML = page; //or newPage
```

You can read more about the .getElementsByTagName() API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName)

Comment: Except that would NOT copy any event listeners, or data attached to elements by page's scripts like jQuery data.

Comment: That said (invalidating the answer in some way), use `document.documentElement` instead of searching.